# Html is taking a while to update using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my codepen link: `http://codepen.io/johnthorlby/pen/KNQdrJ`

This is the code that I have to change my html.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quote").on("click", function(){
      $("#quote h1").text("\"" + "Here is the quote.");
      $("#quote h4").text("- " + "John Thorlby.")
    });
  });
</script>
```

When you click the new quote button it is very temperamental and doesn't always work and when it does it takes a while. What am I doing wrong? This is why way I was taught to do it from freecodecamp.com

Comment: You have two elements with id=quote

Comment: In the future post all your code in the question. Stackoverflow has snipplets which is just like codepen

Comment: There is a typo in your html.. `class-"quote"`

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WozERY

Comment: Thanks for the help all & sorry about that, will post all the code next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the button id is `quote` and so is your div id. So the thing is happening here is you have to click on the div to make the function execute.

Change the button id, then use that id for the `click` function selector.

Hope this helps..